# python loop with boolean statement only runs once

Tags: python, list, loops, boolean

```
def test(wList,fList):
    outfile = open("ignore.txt","w")
    stopWords = ['in','it','a','an','and','to','of','the','for',]

    for i in range(len(wList)):
        x=0
        if wList[i]==stopWords[x]:
            print(stopWords[x],fList[i], file=outfile)
            x=x+1
```

I am trying to compare two lists of different sizes (wList and stopWords). When they match at wList[ i ] and stopWords[ x ] I want to move on to the next word inside of stopWords.

Comment: You reset `x` to zero for every iteration. Perhaps you want to move the assignment before the loop?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski that did the trick. I still have a slight problem however, the word 'an' in stopWords isn't present at all in wList, and it prevents the rest of the words from being compared. Is there a way to move on to the next word in stopWords if it is not present in wList?

Comment: @Jack your comparison criteria is vague. Could you give input and expected output samples, so we understand it better?

Comment: @kiruwka I did some research and found out the real problem. While searching through wList I am only looking for one word at a time. As such, I can pass over other words in the list and it would not register as a match. Is there a way I can reset i to zero after every success?

Comment: if you give an example input and what the program should output, it will be much easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

something like that?

```
def test(wList,fList):
    with open("ignore.txt","w") as outfile:
        stopWords = ['in','it','a','an','and','to','of','the','for',]

        for i in range(len(wList)):
            for word in stopWords:
                if wList[i]==word:
                    print(word, fList[i], file=outfile)
                    break
```

Comment: yes. you are a god.